# javaSpace Security error

Tags: java, javaspaces

Trying work with the TransactionManager but getting the error (see below) everytime the application is run.

```
Error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4160" "connect,resolve")
```

I attempted to google the issue and while not everyone had the same error, people suggested similar to this would fix it (see below). I've no clue how I apply this, if it goes into eclipse with the project or if its run as a batch file?

```
java -Djava.security.policy=/local/public/chs2546/policy.all HelloWorldNotify
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Are you using some IDE (for ex. Eclipse) or you run your code from console?

Comment: This is absolutely my problem too

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250689/javaspace-exception-on-serviceregistrar-call